# Does a light wave that has been cancelled by another light wave continue traveling forward?

Tags: visible-light, waves, speed-of-light, wave-particle-duality

I imagine that if a light wave is cancelled out by another light wave, it would still continue to exist as a photon that is traveling at the speed of light--only without a wavelength. Would it behave only as a particle after it has been cancelled or does it exhibit some other kind of behavior?

Answer (score 3):

No. Wave and particle properties of light exists at the same time and existence of both is required for existence of light.

When it comes to *fully* cancelling out light wave, it's not possible. When interference happens, there're always constructive spots to counterbalance destructive ones. On constructive spots, photon density is high and on destructive spots, photon density is low.

Answer (score 0):

According to Louis de-Broglie (December 12, 1929):

"A wave must be associated with each corpuscle and only the study of the wave's propagation will yield information to us on the successive positions of the corpuscle in space."

So, your idea of the propagation of photon alone is not true according to Broglie's prediction.